# How To Upgrade Pear To Send Email With Smtp send() Function In PHP

Tags: email, smtp, php5, ubuntu-14.04, pear

I want to send e-mail on ubuntu 14.04 with smtp php. But I can't send e-mail because smtp-->send function doesn't work. So that I decided to install pear mail packages. But when ı want to install php pear mail packages on my terminal the error occurs. For example error occurs as below when ı entered "sudo pear install Mail_Mime" command to my terminal.

```
downloading Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz (33,796 bytes)
.........done: 33,796 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/tmp/pear/install/Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz"
Download of "pear/Mail_Mime" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail_Mime"
Download failed
install failed
```

Because of this errors I decided to upgrade the pear which is in my system.I entered "pear upgrade" command the error occurs as below..

```
pear/pear dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.2.3 is not the
recommended version 1.2.1, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/XML_Util cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
No valid packages found
upgrade failed
```

I executed "pear clear-cache, pear update-channels" commands before " pear upgrade" command. All commands executed but "pear upgrade" didn't work because of errors as above.

$mail = @$smtp->send(.. , .., ..); function doesn't work. So that mail isn't sended.This send() function worked with 1.9.4 version of pear, 5.3.10 version of php and ubuntu 12.04. But it doesn't work with 1.9.4 version of pear,5.5.9 php and ubuntu 14.04.

I added "sendmail_path" part to php.ini file.But again I couldn't install pear mail packages on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First run pear to download the packages. It will probably put the packages into
/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/ but it can't install them.

Un-Gzip the downloaded packages.

```
gunzip /build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/*.tar
```

Now pear should be able to work with the pure tar-files.

```
pear upgrade /build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/*.tar
```

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2014-April/111712.html